# Controller test always giving undefined $scope

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am just trying to get started unit testing Angular code and am trying to use Karma and Jasmine for testing. I have checked through several different tutorials and have emulated their code, but every time, the $scope is undefined in my test. I have been working all day on this, have read every related Stackoverflow question (a couple seemed related but did not get answered), keep making things simpler and simpler to narrow down the problem, etc. I am about to pull my hair out. If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it greatly!

karma.config.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Aug 11 2015 11:40:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'Scripts/angular-min.js',
      'Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
      'Scripts/angular-route-min.js',
      'Scripts/angular-resource.min.js',
      'Scripts/hr-module.js',
      'Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js',
      'Scripts/Employee/*.js'

    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        'Scripts/_references.js',
        'Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.intellisense.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

simple-controller.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('hrModule').controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {        
        $scope.greeting = "hello world";        
    }]);


}());
```

Test for simple-controller:

```
'use strict';

describe('SimpleController', function () {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('hrModule'));

    var $controller,
        scope,
        SimpleController;


    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        SimpleController = $controller('SimpleController', { $scope: scope });
    }));


    it('says hello world', function () {
        expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    });    

});
```

I keep getting an ($injector:modulerr) error when I run it, and says "Expected undefined to be defined". If anyone can see any issues here, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: When you **click** on the modulerr link on the console.. what does it say? Also have you loaded the script that declares the module `angular.module('hrModule', [...])` ?

Comment: Yes, the hr-module.js file is actually the one that creates the hrModule (I should have either mentioned or included the code for that). And being on Windows, I can't click anything in the console lol. But there is a ton of encoded data after that error, so I am assuming that is probably the information that would have shown up if I could, but I am unable to read it. If there is good information there that I am missing, I could try the code on another setup and see if I could see it.

Comment: What do you mean by "on windows". I am talking about the browser console. Or just copy paste that url from the browser and hit it. Also try using non minified angularjs for dev which will give you more elaborate message. Generally cause for these errors are easy to identify if you follow the error link in the console.

Comment: OHHH, sorry. This is on Karma test runner. The code actually works just fine without the tests in the browser. That is the reason why I am so confused. I also knew that *nix has a much better shell, but I was thinking "Wow, you can click error messages in it and see a message?" But still, that encoded goop that is showing in the console after the error message is likely what would be shown if this error was occuring in the browser. Although a browser does come up with Karma, it appears to be cleared so it does not seem possible to see any errors in it.

Comment: I should probably pull karma out of the equation and just run Jasmine in the browser to get better error messages and to factor Karma out as being a possible source of the problem.

Comment: You could set karma option singlerun false and debug it in the browser (by hitting the karma url) as well if you want.

Comment: Karma appears to be clearing out the console. I made sure singlerun was set to false and then tried to hit the karma port, and I just got the same minimalist Karma page with nothing in the console except a notice that Karma had cleared the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, PSL for working with me on this. I really appreciate you coming back to keep offering tips.

However, the solution was much more mundane than that. It was an incompatibility between the angular.js file that I had grabbed from Nuget (the most recent release, 1.4.x) and the angular-mock.js script I had downloaded from a tutorial link (1.3.3). For some reason this caused modulerr error that had me baffled, but I figured it out while rebuilding a smaller test project with the same files to test it in the browser.

So if anyone else is getting an error like this, open your angular library files and ensure that they all share the same version number!!

Comment: Actually, sorry I believe it was an issue with using the most recent version of Jasmine and the older version of angular-mock.js. Either way, grabbing angular-mock.js v1.4.4 should correct the issue.